# jQuery Show Image Next to Mouse on Element Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I've got a column of elements in a table, basically:

```
__________________
Element 1 | data1
Element 2 | data2
Element 3 | data3
Element 4 | data4
Element 5 | data5
```

There is an image associated with each `data`, stored as an attribute `data-source`.

I'm trying to get the functionality where, when a user hovers over `data1`,`data2`, ... `data5`, it shows the image next to the mouse associated with that element.

The issue I'm facing is that about 80% of the time the image will show at the correct location, the other 20% it shows at the location of the last image. This is not going to work because the images will be of varying size.

I'm also noticing when hovering over the element, there is a lot of flicker when showing the image (if you move your mouse but are still hovering over the element).

Here's the code I've got:

Html:

```
<tbody class="task-group">
    <tr class="row-major row">
        <td class="col-lg-2 points-col-major">0</td>
        <td class="col-lg-1 proof-col-major spreadsheet-proof no-pad">
            <label for="file-proof-4" class="text-center non-bold proof-none proof-thumbnail" style="width:77px;line-height:39px;margin:0;">None</label>
            <input type="file" id="file-proof-4" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" style="display:none;width:77px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-minor row">
        <td class="col-lg-2 points-col-minor">0</td>
        <td class="col-lg-7 task-col-minor">Test col</b></td>
        <td class="col-lg-1 proof-col-minor spreadsheet-proof no-pad">
            <label for="file-proof-5" class="text-center non-bold proof-none proof-thumbnail" style="width:77px;line-height:39px;margin:0">None</label>
            <input type="file" id="file-proof-5" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" style="display:none;width:77px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<div id="spreadsheet-image-thumbnail-container">
    <img id="spreadsheet-image-thumbnail">
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Show image on hover
$(".spreadsheet-proof > .proof-thumbnail").on({

    // handlerIn
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail").attr("src", "/assets/img/user_uploaded_images/" + $(this).attr("data-proof-source"));

        var proofImage = document.getElementById("spreadsheet-image-thumbnail");
        console.log(e.clientX);
        console.log(proofImage.naturalWidth);
        console.log(e.clientX - proofImage.naturalWidth + 30);
        var x = (e.clientX - proofImage.naturalWidth + 30) + 'px';
        var y = (e.clientY) + 'px';

        $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail-container").css({
            "left": x,
            "top": y,
        });
        $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail").show();
        $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail-container").show();
    },
    // handlerOut
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail-container").hide();
        $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail").hide();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail-container {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

I would like the image to show up next to the cursor in this fashion:

Hovering over element 5:

[image]

Hovering over element 2:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code snippet does not work. Please post working HTML block.

Comment: var proofImage = document.getElementById("spreadsheet-image-thumbnail"); - since you are already in jquery it can be simplyfied as:  var proofImage = $("#spreadsheet-image-thumbnail");

Comment: Sorry, the code is generated via PHP. Let me get you what is generated, one second

Comment: Updated html @shaochuancs

Comment: Is this any help? http://www.scriptol.com/css/tooltip.php

Comment: It looks like it might. I will test it tomorrow and let you know, thank you!

Comment: @Sej your code does not work, there is no `Element 1` `Data 1` etc.